# Gutenberg ServerSideRender Callback

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I am trying to trigger a callback function on Server Side Render:

```
edit: function( props ) {
    return [
        el( ServerSideRender, {
            block: 'meetongo/meetup-slider',
            attributes: props.attributes,
            onChange: function( props ) {
                console.log('hello world');
            }
        } ),
    ];
},
```

This method is used in [PlayList](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/pull/7126/files) block which in my case is not triggered.

Comment: Unless, you share the full block code. We can't fully understand what's causing the issue.